# Why are these seemingly identical Golang structs not equal?

Tags: go, testing

I'm trying to learn Golang testing.

I'm comparing 2 seemingly identical stucts but they are not equal. What is going wrong?

```
2020/01/22 17:10:10 ****2 cities[0] is type *main.City has &main.City{Name:"Boston", State:"", Country:"USA", Capital:true, Population:685000} 
2020/01/22 17:10:10 ****2 expected  is type *main.City has &main.City{Name:"Boston", State:"", Country:"USA", Capital:true, Population:685000} 
2020/01/22 17:10:11 Preparing to DELETE 5 city docs
--- FAIL: TestCities (3.08s)
    --- FAIL: TestCities/Test_POST_should_add_New_City (0.62s)
        city_handlers_test.go:68: Why is ( cities[0] != expected )Boston was not added to Firestore: 
             got &{Boston  USA true 685000}  
             want &{Boston  USA true 685000}
FAIL
exit status 1
```

Here is the test:

```golang
        // why don't these structs match?
        log.Printf("****2 cities[0] is type %T has %#v \n", cities[0], cities[0])
        log.Printf("****2 expected  is type %T has %#v \n", expected, expected)
        // why is this comparison failing when both are the same type with the same values?
        if cities[0] != expected {
            t.Errorf("Why is ( cities[0] != expected )Boston was not added to Firestore: \n got %v  \n want %v", cities[0], expected)
        }
```

Comment: Please show all your code, or at least an example of what `expected` might be and how it is created. Is the `expected` variable an `interface{}` value or a `City` struct value?

Comment: [Axifive's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59869314/1256452) is no doubt correct: you are comparing pointer values, not the underlying object content. You probably wanted `if *cities[0] != *expected` here. See Playground example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/dDaJalcLg4h).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compare pointers, and it looks like they point to different objects. For the correct check, you should compare objects' fields.

This packages can help you to do this: [reflect.DeepEqual()](https://godoc.org/reflect#DeepEqual), [testify.EqualValues()](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#Assertions.EqualValues), [cmp.Equal()](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp#Equal)

Example:
https://play.golang.org/p/09BYFeYj5xx